# Laravel: Cannot route to expected URL

Tags: php, laravel, url, view, routes

Here is my nav-bar:

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="list-group-item">
            <li><a href="/posts"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;All Post</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/posts/create"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Create New Post</a></li>
            <li><a href="/posts/manage"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-tasks"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Manage Posts</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

and here is my route.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'posts'], function(){
Route::get('', 'PostController@index');
Route::get('create', 'PostController@create');
Route::post('confirm', 'PostController@confirmation');
Route::get('{postID}', 'PostController@show');
Route::get('posts/manage', 'PostController@manage');});
```

I expect when I click on the "Manage Posts" button, it will redirect me to function `manage()` in my `PostController`.

But when I click on it, it redirects to a view which belongs to `storage/framework/views` which is `show()` in my `PostController`.

I don't know why and how to make it to the right url.

Can somebody help me with this one please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your link links to `/posts/management`, not `/posts/manage`. Second, you already have the prefix `posts` for this route-group, so the route `posts/manage` will be available under the url `/posts/posts/manage`.

You also want to move the `manage` route before your `{postID}` route, because `{postID}` will just catch *anything*, so the router has to first check the manage-route, and only if it doesn't match, the catch-all route.

And you should control what is accepted as a valid `postID` using [Route Parameters: Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).

`Route::get('{postID}', 'PostController@show')->where('id', '[0-9]+');`

Comment: Yeah i forgot to change it back. I met this problem so i am trying to take it to a new url to see if that problem is gone but it is still the same. All other route s are doing fine and working properly except manage one.

Comment: Thank you so much, move the `manage` route before `{postID}` does the trick.

Comment: When i move the `manage` route upward, `Route::get('{postID}, 'PostController@show');` doesn't work anymore. It returns a blank page. Can you give me a solution?

Comment: You forgot a `'` there.